# declaring variables in loop

Tags: memory, declaration

I was wondering whenever you declare a variable in a loop it has during that loop the same address in memory? Why happens this? After the loop if i declare it again it has another memory address.

If it has the same address how can i do something like this

```
 `char *p[100]
     cin>>n;
     for(i=0;i<n;++i)
      {char b[100];
         cin>>b;
        p[i]=b;
      }`
```

In the end when i want to display the value of p[i] but b has the same address and i end up with the same address in p[i]. How can this be done without dinamic memory allocation? It can be done like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare a variable inside loop its memory is allocated only once, its value may change during loop but not address thats why it will show same memory.
if you declare it again after loop then this variable is not in scope of loop, variable in C have block scope. Then it is treated as new variable and new memory is allocated for it.

Read more about scope of variable.
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-rules-in-c/

Comment: and why the memory remains the same in the loop?It is compiler optimization or usually behavior? The compiler dont declare it everytime it goes through that declaration? Why it is declaring in the same exact place?

Comment: It is designed like this because it don't need. you can imagine how much inefficient it would be if it allocates 1000 times memory for a single variable in loop.